# Pandas sum two dataframes based on the value of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two *dataframes* that I want to sum along the `y` axis, conditionally.

For example:

> df_1

```
a    b    value
1    1    1011
1    2    1012
2    1    1021
2    2    1022
```

> df_2

```
a    b    value
9    9    99
1    2    12
2    1    21
```

I want to make `df_1['value'] -= df_2['value'] if df_1[a] == df_2[a] & df_1[b] == df_2[b]`, so the output would be:

> OUTPUT

```
a    b    value
1    1    1011
1    2    1000
2    1    1000
2    2    1022
```

Is there a way to achieve that instead of iterating the whole *dataframe*? (It's pretty big)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of index alignment that `pandas` provides here, by setting `a` and `b` as your index before subtracting.

---

```
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)

df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0).reindex(df1.index)
```

```
      value
a b
1 1  1011.0
  2  1000.0
2 1  1000.0
  2  1022.0
```

Comment: As I need the original structure, I ended up with: `df1 = df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0).reindex(df1.index).reset_index()`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

You could also perform a left join and subtract matching values. Here is how to do that:

```
(pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='left', on=['a', 'b'], suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
 .fillna(0)
 .assign(value=lambda x: x.value_1 - x.value_2)
)[['a', 'b', 'value']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could let

```
merged = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['a', 'b'], left_index=True)
df_1.value[merged.index] = merged.value_x - merged.value_y
```

Result:

```
In [37]: df_1
Out[37]:
   a  b  value
0  1  1   1011
1  1  2   1000
2  2  1   1000
3  2  2   1022
```